# VisualStudio/C++ trouble with conformance mode using templates/inheritance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I created the following as a toy example that reproduces the problem I'm having with my larger code base. I'm trying to use a virtual overloaded type-cast operator in a class template. While the code works perfectly in Visual Studio with conformance mode disabled ('permissive'), I get an error when using strict conformance mode. I'd like to know if there's something wrong with this implementation because it's important that this code library is portable. Can anyone help me understand if there's something wrong with this?

When I try to compile the line:

`Shape<dim, dim> retval = Square<dim>::operator Shape<dim, dim>();`

I get an error C7527 'dim': template parameter name cannot be redeclared

I cannot find any documentation of error C7527. I'm using VS 2019.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <int length, int width>
class Shape
{
public:
    int GetLength() { return length; }
    int GetWidth() { return width; }
    int Area() { return length * width; }
    int Volume() { return length * width * height; }
    void SetHeight(int height_in) { height = height_in; }
private:
    int height;
};

template <int size>
class Square
{
public:
    virtual operator Shape<size, size>() const
    {
        Shape<size, size> retval;
        retval.SetHeight(0u);
        return retval;
    }
};

template<int dim>
class Cube : public Square<dim>
{
public:
    virtual operator Shape<dim, dim>() const override
    {
        Shape<dim, dim> retval = Square<dim>::operator Shape<dim, dim>();
        retval.SetHeight(dim);
        return retval;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cube<3> myCube;
    Shape<3, 3> myShape = Shape<3, 3>(myCube);
    cout << myShape.Volume() << endl;
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/4bbWhb). What MSVC version are you using? Anyway, try this as a workaround: `typedef Shape<dim, dim> MyShape; MyShape retval = Square<dim>::operator MyShape();`

Comment: I can reproduce it; just set the MSVC version to latest: https://godbolt.org/z/rj6G8EYhb